# Closing Tabs in Qt, multiple tabs close at once?

Tags: c++, qt, tabs, tabbing

So I've been about some sites for examples of code for a function to close tabs. I set the tabs to closable (that went absolutely fine), but the problem I have is that when I close tabs (specifically, the second tab onwards), it closes every tab after that one.

My header:

```
private slots:
void on_btn_newTab_clicked();
void on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index);
```

My cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index)
{
    connect(ui -> tabWidget, SIGNAL(tabCloseRequested(int)), this, SLOT(closeTab(int)));
}

void MainWindow::closeTab(int index)
{
    ui -> tabWidget -> removeTab(index);
}
```

Am I missing something? I assumed it was because I hadn't specified an index to close a specific tab, but then I thought the parameter for this slot was the index I needed. Am I wrong?

Comment: why are you even trying to close the tab yourself ? isn't QTabWidget already taking care of this ?

Comment: I had to implement this code in order to actually remove the tabs. When you set tabs to closable, all it does is show a little clickable 'x', but doesn't necessarily close the tab when you click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think the connect part is right..

On `on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index)` you should call `ui->tabWidget->removeTab(index)` not connect a signal ..

I think that you create extra signals and thats why you remove all tabs after the tab you tried to close.

EDIT:

To expand a bit:

I think, on first click no tabs get deleted, but you create a connection to delete a tab with the `on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index)`. On your second try you again, create a connection with `on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index)` and call `closeTab`. On your third try you create another connection and call `closeTab` twice with the same index, so the tab you clicked is deleted and the next one ...

Comment: That fixed the problem, thanks!

Also, thanks for the theory behind it, always willing to learn new things!